# passing old value back to javabean from javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, javabeans

I have this piece of javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_confirm()
{

var type = '<%= nameBean.getTxnType() %>';
var old_cd = '<%= nameBean.getCode() %>';
var new_cd = document.getElementById("tbCode").value;
var cd;

if (type == "Update")
  {
    if(old_cd != new_cd)
    { 
        var response = confirm("Code already exists. Do you want to replace it?");
        if (response){
                    document.NameUpdate.submit();
        }
        else{
            cd = old_cd;

    }
  }
</script>
```

and this is what i am doing in my jsp page to invoke this script:

```
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="action" onclick="show_confirm()" VALUE="Save Changes">
```

Its working fine when I hit ok.. but my question is how can i pass the value of old_cd back to the bean so it wont update it with the new code that was entered by the user in the tbcode box.. when user hit cancel i want to ignore what value was entered in textbox and not to update that field in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on the use case here, but here are a couple of answers:

If the question is, "how do I stop the form from submitting when the user hits cancel?", then the answer is, return `false` in the click handler:

```
if (response){
    document.NameUpdate.submit();
}
else{
    cd = old_cd;
    return false;
}
```

If you need to submit the form no matter which one the user clicks, then you probably need to submit the old value in a hidden `input` field and have a way to tell the server that user hit "cancel" (probably another hidden field), e.g.:

```
<!-- html -->
<input type="hidden" name="old_cd" value="<%= nameBean.getCode() %>">
<input type="hidden" id="canceled" name="canceled" value="0">
```

and javascript:

```
// js snippet
if (response){
    document.NameUpdate.submit();
}
else{
    document.getElementById("canceled").value = 1;
    return true;
}
```